# How does go program link system libs, when compiled on other OS?

Tags: go, linker

I understand GO code can be compiled for different platforms (OS).

Lets say I compile on Windows for Linux.
If I need a dependency to a Linux system lib - how is this dependency resolved?

Comment: By definition, if a dependency is specific to Linux, it can't be resolved when compiling for windows.

Comment: So that means, that then I cant compile such a program on windows?

Comment: If a component only works on Linux, you can't compile it for windows. The obvious answer is a tautology, so maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could come up with an actual example?

Comment: If you're using cgo to call out to external libraries, you must have those libraries available at compile time, just like you would with any other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, like to reference system libs of another OS, 
for example linux system libs when compiling from windows - 
the linux system libs must be present on the windows system.

The same would be the case, when using special libs, for example when calling c-libs using "cgo", which maybe could implement some device specific functions.
For example on a coffee machine - the functions which starts making coffee or cleaning the machine.